# Why won't character stay at the x-axis rotation I set In the inspector?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, transformation, quaternion

Here is a snippet of my Update function, which contains everything regarding my rotations for the character:

```
// Higher the Z float, the LESS of a rotation when moving
Vector3 v3 = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"), 0.0f, 1.5f); 

// A Quaternion variable named "quaternion" that's equal to LookRotation class that takes 
// the "v3" variable
Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.LookRotation (v3); 

// The actual rotation is done using the Slerp class
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (
  transform.rotation, 
  quaternion, 
  Rotspeed * Time.deltaTime); 

// When Countdown timer is done, then the animator is enabled
adventureAnimator.enabled = true;
```

When I put "357" on the X-Axis tab of Rotation, why does it go back to 0 whenever the game starts? After some debugging I know it is because of my logic contained in my "transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp" line of code. What do I need to change?

If you need more information or need me to elaborate, please let me know.

Comment: what is `Rotspeed` set to?

Answer (score 1):

Having tested your code, I find that your problem occurs due to several faults.

- Your telling your rotation to move with a time value of `Rotspeed * Time.deltaTime`. I have previously mistaken this value to represent *how long* the rotation should take. If you have taken the same misinterpretation, there is a good chance your *actually* telling it to complete the rotation *immediately*.
- Your telling your rotation to move between 357 degrees and 0 degrees. That gives us only 3 degrees of rotation, which is not a lot. Depending on your setup, you might very well be completing the rotation in such a small amount of time that you simply do not notice.
- As *InfiniteCanvas* points out, your taking `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` at *every* `Update()` call. Whenever your not providing input, this will return a value of `0`.

### Using `Quaternion.Slerp`

Since you have neglected to tell us what you are setting `Rotspeed` to, this could easily be a red herring. That said, I see this error a lot, and have made it myself when first starting to use `Quaternion.Slerp`.

[As per the API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html), the method takes two `Quaternion` values to represent the start and finish rotations, and a `float` to represent the time. While *time* is commonly interpreted as "how long should my rotation take", it is actually a *normal* for *how quickly* your object should *complete* the rotation.

If the combined value of `Rotspeed * time.deltaTime` reaches the value of `1`, your effectively telling your code "perform the entire rotation in a single frame". This will move the rotation *immediately* to the `b` quaternion, in this case, `(0, 0, 0)`.

---

***This is the only fault that specifically results in your reported problem***. All other potential faults result in a *similar* problem, but instead of skipping straight to 0, the rotation still "teeters" for a little. For example, with the *input* problem, rotation moves back and fourth between -0.01 and 0.01.

### Understanding `Transform.Rotation`

There is a possibility you interpret the move between `(357, 0, 0)` and `(0, 0, 0)` to be quite large; the gap between 357 and 0. It is important to know that this is *not* the case.

The rotation displayed on the transform via the inspector *can* be interpreted as *degrees*. You can submit *any* value, but as soon as you hit play, the transform will scale these values back to the *true* degrees. Once a rotation value reaches 360, it has performed a full rotation. It may as well be returned to 0 - and that is exactly what it does. You can see this by setting the rotation to values *higher* than 360, via the inspector. Once you hit play, these numbers will immediately scale down to values between 0 and 360.

As you can see, rotation between 357 and 0 is not that much - it is *actually* only a difference of 3. The object is rotated *clockwise*, and once it reaches a rotation of 360, the transform resets this value to 0. The `Quaternion.Slerp()` is successfully carried out over a mere *3* degrees.

### Ensuring Input

As mentioned by *InfiniteCanvas*, constantly updating your rotation means that whenever the user is not actually providing input, you will update your rotation to 0. This might have a secondary effect on your logic, as you might reset the *look at* rotation when you do not mean to. Further testing has confirmed that this alone will not cause the problem you describe, but it is worth addressing how you might better your input.

Keep in kind that if you did not intend to pass non-values at `Update()`, you will want to declare `Vector3 v3` as a *class variable* rather than a *method variable*. This way, if your current input as a non-value, you still have the rotation from your last value input.

---

Continuing use of the Input Manager, you could simply exclude non-input in an 
if statement, prior to setting it as your new rotation:

```
// we should initialise the vector with a default value.
Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(0, 0, 1.5f);

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
    {
        Vector3 v3 = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"), 0.0f, 1.5f); 
    }

    ...
}
```

---

You might consider checking direct key presses to influence a set vector, instead. Ideally, you would set a class variable to represent `rotationMovement` per input update. You could than tailor your code to rotate *once* per key press with `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode)`, during *ever* update where the key is pressed with `Input.GetKey(KeyCode)`, or even *once* at the update where the key is *released* with `Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode)`. The choice is yours, but it would look something like this:

```
// we should initialise the vector with a default value.
Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(0, 0, 1.5f);
float rotationMovement = 0.1f;

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        v3.x -= rotationMovement;
    }
    else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        v3.x += rotationMovement;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap it all in an `if` statement, like so:

```
if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
{
    //your code
}
```

As it is now it updates on every frame, regardless of your input. That means that you update your rotation to

```
v3 = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1.5f)
```

when you're not pressing anything.

Comment: Reversing my vote as I have found this answer to be incorrect. Copying the above code, a vector of (0, 0, 1.5) does not lead to *any* rotation. The rotation *stays* at 357.